# ERROR - DNS lookup failed for broker:29092 (0)

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am running a kafka streaming project on pycharm. All the dependencies like kafka,broker,airflow,spark are running on docker.

i have a python script which includes reading data from API and publishing to kafka topic.

```
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'], max_block_ms=5000)

    producer.send('users_created', json.dumps(str(res)).encode('utf-8'))
```

When i execute this code on my pycharm tool i receive an error saying:

`[2023-12-06T18:55:08.339+0530] {conn.py:315} ERROR - DNS lookup failed for broker:29092 (0) [2023-12-06T18:55:08.339+0530] {conn.py:1205} INFO - Probing node bootstrap-0 broker version [2023-12-06T18:55:11.062+0530] {conn.py:1527} WARNING - DNS lookup failed for broker:29092, exception was [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed. Is your advertised.listeners (called adverti    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'],max_block_ms=5000) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\avita\PycharmProjects\kafka-spark(python)\venv\Lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 381, in __init__ client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer', ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\avita\PycharmProjects\kafka-spark(python)\venv\Lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 244, in __init__ self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\avita\PycharmProjects\kafka-spark(python)\venv\Lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 927, in check_version raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable() kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable`

What could be the possible reason behind the error?
My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
#      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:INTERNAL://kafka_broker_1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
```